# How to update scraping link in for loop

Tags: python, web-scraping

I developed this program to scrape newegg for ps4 prices. However I want to scrape multiple pages. Here is what I have but once it scrapes the first page the program stops. Basically I am trying to change the link so 'pages-1' changes to 2,3,4 etc. Is there a better way to do this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

page_num = 1
prod_num = 0
source = requests.get('https://www.newegg.com/PS4-Systems/SubCategory/ID-3102/Page-' + str(page_num) + '?PageSize=36&order=BESTMATCH').text


soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

csv_file = open('newegg_scrape.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['Product', 'Price', 'Shipping_info'])



for info in soup.find_all('div', class_='item-container'):
    prod = info.find('a', class_='item-title').text.strip()
    price = info.find('li', class_='price-current').text.strip().splitlines()[1].replace(u'\xa0', '')
    if  u'$' not in price:
        price = info.find('li', class_='price-current').text.strip().splitlines()[0].replace(u'\xa0', '')
    ship = info.find('li', class_='price-ship').text.strip()
    print(prod)
    print(price)
    print(ship)
    csv_writer.writerow([prod, price, ship])
    prod_num += 1
    if prod_num > 35: #there is about 35 items per newegg page
        page_num += 1

   # print(price.splitlines()[1])
    print('-----------')
csv_file.close()
```

Comment: is their any limit on page_num?

Comment: Sure lets make it 5 pages

Answer (score 0):

i found the page limit num here

[image]

and i think you can get the page limit by xpath or other ways:

```py
# xpath syntax may like this 

# //span[@class='list-tool-pagination-text']
```

hope it's useful for you

Comment: Sorry but i'm a little confused to what this does?

Comment: for your question, you wanna change the link like  'pages-1' , 'pages-2',...,'pages-n', i think that if you get the page limit then you can get all pages links

Answer (score 0):

If you noticed, Next "button" tag of last page has attribute "disabled", So [tag_name].has_attr('disabled') return True . Using this you can manage pagination.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
csv_file = open('newegg_scrape.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['Product', 'Price', 'Shipping_info'])
URL_PART1 = "https://www.newegg.com/PS4-Systems/SubCategory/ID-3102/Page-"
URL_PART2 = "?PageSize=36&order=BESTMATCH"
PAGE_NO = 1
url = URL_PART1 + str(PAGE_NO) + URL_PART2
while len(url):
    PAGE_NO+=1
    resp = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
    all_divs = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'item-info'})
    for item in all_divs:
        prod = ""
        price = ""
        ship = ""
        # get product name
        prod = item.find('a', attrs={'class':'item-title'})
        if prod:
            prod = prod.text.strip()

        # get price
        price_part = item.find('li', attrs={'class':'price-current'})
        if price_part:
            price_part1 = price_part.strong
            if price_part1:
                price_part1 = price_part1.text.strip()
            price_part2 = price_part.sup
            if price_part2:
                price_part2 = price_part2.text.strip()
        if price_part1 and price_part2:
            price = price_part1 + price_part2

        # get shipping info
        ship = item.find('li', attrs={'class':'price-ship'})
        if ship:
            ship = ship.text.strip()

        csv_writer.writerow([prod, price, ship])

    # manage pagination
    next_button = soup.find('button', attrs={'title': 'Next'})
    if not(next_button.has_attr('disabled')):
        url = URL_PART1 + str(PAGE_NO) + URL_PART2
    else:
        url = ""
```